# How to wait until an AWS CloudFormation stack creation or update is completed in bash?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

I have a use-case where my bash script needs to wait until AWS CloudFormation completes Creating or Updating the stacks.

I found the following commands can be used to do so:

```
aws cloudformation wait stack-create-complete --stack-name STACK_NAME

aws cloudformation wait stack-update-complete --stack-name STACK_NAME
```

**Following is a snippet of the script -**

```
echo "Creating stack ..."

aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name $STACK_NAME \
--parameters  ParameterKey=Environment,ParameterValue=Development \
--template-body file://someCfScript.yaml \
--capabilities CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND --profile someProfileName

aws cloudformation wait stack-create-complete --stack-name $STACK_NAME
```

But I am not able to do so and I get the following error:

```
{
    "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:ap-southeast-1:someAwsAcId:stack/someStackName/xxxx-xxx-xx-xxx-xxxxx"
}

Waiter StackCreateComplete failed: Waiter encountered a terminal failure state
```

And instead of waiting, the script goes to the next line, causing things to break.

Answer (score 4):

Wait for a new stack creation -- `aws cloudformation wait stack-create-complete --stack-name STACK_NAME`

Wait for an existing stack update -- `aws cloudformation wait stack-update-complete --stack-name STACK_NAME`

```
wait_stack_create() {
    STACK_NAME=$1

    echo "Waiting for [$STACK_NAME] stack creation."

    aws cloudformation wait stack-create-complete \
    --region ${REGION}  \
    --stack-name ${STACK_NAME}
    status=$?

    if [[ ${status} -ne 0 ]] ; then
        # Waiter encountered a failure state.
        echo "Stack [${STACK_NAME}] creation failed. AWS error code is ${status}."

        exit ${status}
    fi
}
```

Function call:

```
wait_stack_create ${TEST_SERVICE_STACK}
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message indicates that the stack reached a terminal failure state. As with anything, if what you're doing fails, you shouldn't continue.

You can get the status of your stack after reaching a terminal state:

```
aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name STACK_NAME --query 'Stacks[].StackStatus' --output text
```

If the status isn't `CREATE_COMPLETE` or `UPDATE_COMPLETE` you should print an error message and exit your script.

Comment: How do I make my script execution wait until CREATE_READY status?

Comment: @Ani - I've added the command to retrieve stack status. I'm assuming you know how to do a conditional in your script.

Answer (score 2):

The wait command expect the stack arn

add to the create stack command `jq -r '.StackId'`

Something like:

```
ID=$(aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name $STACK_NAME \
--parameters  ParameterKey=Environment,ParameterValue=Development \
--template-body file://someCfScript.yaml \
--capabilities CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND --profile someProfileName| jq -r '.StackId')
```

And then you can do

```
aws cloudformation wait stack-create-complete --stack-name "${STACKID}"
```

Answer (score -1):

You are waiting for [stack-update-complete](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/cloudformation/wait/stack-update-complete.html) which waits for:

> Wait until stack status is UPDATE_COMPLETE.

However, you are creating stack, not updating it. Thus, you should be waiting for [stack-create-complete](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/cloudformation/wait/stack-create-complete.html):

> Wait until stack status is CREATE_COMPLETE.

Comment: I'm doing aws cloudformation wait stack-create-complete --stack-name stackNameHere after creating the cf stack, but getting the error, added snippet to the question